# SSRS Matrix not sorting when set in both tablix and row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2014

I have a matrix, as in the picture below, which I have set to sort by the Total invoiced.  Field is being returned from the Db as a number, I just formatted it as currency in the field (sorry it is a bit ugly with the names removed, but its live data).  However as in the picture below , it is not sorting on the total invoiced.  I have set it to sort by TotalInvoiced in both the row group properties and the Tablix properties, with no luck.  Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

[image: Matrix not sorting]

[image]

Sorting added on the administrator group for the Total invoiced column.  Visit year sorted on itself, VistiMonth sorted on itself (month in numbers) to show progression.

Comment: Can you show the actual report design including the row and column groups and their group/sort properties. It looks more like table than a matrix to me but seeing the design will help.

Comment: Added the information above, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the sorting that is based on TotalInvoiced, just so you have a clean starting point.

Now check that your VisitYear and VisitMonth are sorted as required.

Finally, set the first sort expression in the AdministratorName RowGroup to

```
=SUM(Fields!TotalInvoiced.Value)
```

Set the Sort direction as required.

That should give you what you want, AdministratorName will be sorted by the sum of the  TotalInvoiced field for that AdministratorName.